# What's wrong with this code? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, debugging

this code works, and it alerts the variable every time.

```
var idNumber;
var elements;
var id;
var blockerIds=[];
var whileLoop=0;
while (whileLoop<112) {
    elements=document.getElementsByName('bid');
    id=elements[whileLoop].getAttribute('id');
    blockerIds[whileLoop]=id;
    alert(blockerIds[whileLoop]);
    whileLoop++;
}
```

but I tried alerting it outside of the while statement, like this:

```
var idNumber;
var elements;
var id;
var blockerIds=[];
var whileLoop=0;
while (whileLoop<112) {
    elements=document.getElementsByName('bid');
    id=elements[whileLoop].getAttribute('id');
    blockerIds[whileLoop]=id;
    whileLoop++;
}
alert(blockerIds);
```

but it only says "undefined". Does anyone know how I can use this variable outside of the while statement, or does it seem like it should work perfectly?

Comment: You should probably put the document.getElementsByName() call outside of your loop.  Just sayin'...

Comment: How many elements are there named `bid`? What are their `id`s?

Comment: Also: if there aren't 112 of them, it will fail

Comment: there are 112 elements named bid, and there ids are "bid'x'_'x'" and x is always a number

Comment: use `console.log()` instead of `alert`, then you also see other error messages, when they occur.

Comment: Why will it fail if there are 112 elements?

Comment: @CPC specifically, if there are fewer than 112, you will be attempting to access an array index that doesn't exist

Comment: Reduced to just two elements for sanity, but it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/YvqpF/

Comment: Also, why loop over a hardcoded number? Why not do `.getElementsByName` before your loop and then use the size of that collection in your loop?

Comment: That's just how I've done it before. I don't see how either way would be better or worse.

Comment: @CPC: It's worse because it fails the second somebody changes the number of elements with the same name. It's horrible to maintain.

Comment: Plus, you're re-retrieving the entire list every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7CF/1/). Fixed your code:

```
var idNumber;
var elements;
var id;
var blockerIds=[];
var whileLoop=0;
elements=document.getElementsByName('bid');
while ((elements.length >= 112 && whileLoop < 112) || (whileLoop < elements.length && elements.length <= 112)) {
    id=elements[whileLoop].getAttribute('id');
    blockerIds[whileLoop]=id;
    whileLoop++;
}
alert(blockerIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

JS is an interpreted language, when it runs, it firstly search all the definitions of var, and give them an undefined value. Even if the var is claimed to have a actual value, it will still be given an undefined value until this line has been eventually executed.

Comment: I don't understand that.

Comment: `var idNumber;
var elements;
var id;
var blockerIds=[];
var whileLoop=0;
elements="123";
while (whileLoop < 3) { // less than 112
    elements=document.getElementsByName('bid');
    id=elements[whileLoop].getAttribute('id');
    blockerIds[whileLoop]=id;
    whileLoop++;
}
alert(blockerIds);`